How to divide a known root out of a polynomial?
Consider this simple 5th order polynomial:
 pol=x^5+x^4+1
 Factor[pol]
(*   (1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^3)   *)
 root=FindInstance[pol==0, x]
(*   -1/2 -I/2 Sqrt[3]   *)

Suppose we would like to see the 4th order polynomial with this root removed.
This does not immediately seem to be easy... For instance:
FullSimplify[pol/(x-root)]
Factor[pol/(x-root)]

are both just returning the fraction of a 5th order polynomial divided by a 1st order one...
How to see the 4th order result explicitly?
(PS: I know it could become a very messy expression, but then I would try one of the other roots. I just need to see the result in order to judge that.)

PolynomialQuotient is enough. I just used PolynomialQuotientRemainder to see that remainder is indeed 0.
PolynomialQuotientRemainder[x^5 + x^4 + 1, x - (-1/2 - I/2 Sqrt[3]), x]


$$\left\{x^4+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) x^3-x^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) x-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2},0\right\}$$

Thanks, that solves it...

FindInstance returns a rule, not a number. Therefore you need:
root = x /. FindInstance[pol == 0, x][[1]]

1/2 (-1 - I Sqrt[3])

To divide the polynomial by the root:
red = PolynomialQuotient[pol, (x - root), x]


Further, "Factor" factors a polynomial over the integers, not the Complexes. Therefore, to get all the roots of "red":
Solve[red == 0, x] // N

{{x -> -0.5 + 0.866025 I}, {x -> -1.32472}, {x -> 
   0.662359 - 0.56228 I}, {x -> 0.662359 + 0.56228 I}}

